# find shared folders with Windows Search in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

Can I quickly find shared folders with Windows Search in Windows 7? At the same time, I also want to quickly find folders that haven't been shared.

Answer (score 1):

I normally use the command line or Computer Management to list shares on the system.

In the command prompt, type:

```
net share
```

to view a list of shared folders with their respective locations and descriptions.